# how can I assign string values to a matrix?

Tags: python, string, matrix

I need to create a 5x5 matrix and be able to assign string values to specific positions, search the string value and return the position, list all values in the matrix.

```
(1,1)  (1,2)  (1,3)  (1,4)  (1,5)
(2,1)  (2,2)  (2,3)  (2,4)  (2,5)
(3,1)  (3,2)  (3,3)  (3,4)  (3,5)
(4,1)  (4,2)  (4,3)  (4,4)  (4,5)
(5,1)  (5,2)  (5,3)  (5,4)  (5,5)
 
1-assing a name to a position
2-remove a name  the position
3-search a name and return the position
4-list all names in the matrix
choose an option: 

example:
choose an option: 1
insert name: jonas
choose the position: 3,2

(*)  (*)  (*)  (*)  (*)
(*)  (*)  (*)  (*)  (*)
(*)(jonas)(*)  (*)  (*)
(*)  (*)  (*)  (*)  (*)
(*)  (*)  (*)  (*)  (*)   * = empty
```

Answer (score 0):

## main function

```
def main():
    matrix = [["*" for _ in range(5)] for _ in range(5)]   # a 5 by 5 matrix

    # this way is also valid but it takes a bit more memory
    # matrix = []
    # for i in range(5):
    #   matrix.append([])
    #   for _ in range(5):
    #       matrix[i].append(["*"])

    # position 
    x = 3
    y = 2

    matrix[y][x] = "Jonas"
    
    return matrix

print(main())
```